# What would be some synonyms for an "artist/band on tour"? "Tourist" would be technically correct but misleading.

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, synonyms

The use will be for a title, caption, heading or headline specifying the musician is only on a short stopover. Example, a photo captioned as 
"(Artist on tour) John Smith with his roadies"

Comment: 'Touring musician' works. Or 'John Smith on tour (or touring) with his roadies.' Tourist is not correct for a traveling artist.

Comment: While 'synonym' does not demand a single word, you may be expecting one, and I'm fairly sure that 'artist/band on tour' doesn't have a single-word synonym.

Comment: Also you will commonly see it referenced as John Smith 2017 World Tour (or whatever level of internationality the group is reaching to).

Comment: *In town for one appearance*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an appropriate *single* word to convey what you mean.  It would probably be better to reword the sentence as "John Smith on tour with his roadies" or "John Smith passing through town on his tour".  As you say in the title, "tourist", doesn't fit with a musician "on tour".

Answer (score 0):

Contracts for the services of musicians often refer generically to the artist as The Artist or The Talent.  The Act is another synonym.

Comment: But don't all those also apply when the band is not on tour?